# Cognito Credentials are not authorized to perform Execute api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I am trying to create a role-based access control using AWS Cognito groups. I have the following Role and policy defined to deny the access to resources

```
CognitoAuthRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        Path: /
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Principal:
                Federated: "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
              Action:
                - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
              Condition:
                StringEquals:
                  "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud":
                    Ref: CognitoIdentityPool
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike":
                  "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": authenticated
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: "CognitoAuthorizedPolicy"
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: "Deny"
                  Action: "*"
                  Resource: "*"
```

And then I created a group called admin incognito user pool and assign a role with a policy to let the user invoke the API as follows

```
CognitoUserPoolGroupAdmin:
  Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolGroup
  Properties:
    UserPoolId:
      Ref: CognitoUserPool
    GroupName: Admin
    Precedence: 0
    RoleArn:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - AdminRole
        - Arn

AdminRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        Path: /
        RoleName: AdminRole
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Principal:
                Federated: "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
              Action:
                - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
              Condition:
                StringEquals:
                  "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud":
                    Ref: CognitoIdentityPool
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike":
                  "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": authenticated
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: CognitoAdminPolicy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: "Allow"
                  Action:
                    - "execute-api:Invoke"
                  Resource:
                    - arn:aws:execute-api:ap-south-1:****:***/*/GET/user
```

And then I created a user and added to the group admin and obtained temp credentials and then tried to invoke the API and got following 403 error in postman

> "User:
>   arn:aws:sts::******:assumed-role/auth-service-dev-CognitoAuthRole-1JO2U7LKRJRBB/CognitoIdentityCredentials
>   is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource:
>   arn:aws:execute-api:ap-south-1:********2015:****/dev/GET/user with an
>   explicit deny"

This was working perfectly and started causing this error after removing and redeploying the cloud formation stacks.

Comment: You have explicit deny for everything in your `CognitoAuthorizedPolicy`. Explicit deny always wins.

Comment: @Marcin. Does not AWS gives more precedence to Group role?

Comment: no. `explicit deny` in any place in a permission evaluation chain overwrites any allow. Check how policies are evaluated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html).

Comment: @Marcin Thank Man you gave me a hint. I have missed to configure *Authenticated role selection* in Authentication Providers section of ID pool. Changing it from "use default role" to "choose role from token* Fixed the issue. And the resource you provided tells me that My understanding of how the evaluation work is wrong.

Comment: No problem. Just added answer for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, the problem was `explicit deny`. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html):

> If the code finds even one explicit deny that applies, the code
>   returns a final decision of Deny.

Basically, `explicit deny` always wins over any `allow`.